# What Star Trek TNG episode involves a strange repeating sound that is a combination of voices on the ship?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

I saw this episode a long time ago, and I can't locate it from the episode guide descriptions.

I remember that there was this eerie noise, and Data was able to distinguish all the sounds as being the simultaneous voices of everyone aboard...

Does anyone know what season/episode this was from?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That was [Cause and Effect](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_%28episode%29).

The ship has been stuck in a time loop, and the crew's voices from previous iterations are audible.

It's actually Dr. Crusher who first hears the voices; Data determines what they are.

Answer (score 4):

The episode is "[Cause and Effect](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_%28episode%29)" (Season 5 episode 18). The episode was directed by Jonathan Frakes (AKA Cmdr Riker) and guest-starred Kelsey Grammer as Captain Morgan Bateson

[image: Morgan Bateson]

*"The destruction of the Enterprise near a distortion in the space-time continuum causes a temporal causality loop to form, trapping the ship and crew in time and forcing them to relive the events that led to their deaths"*

The voices themselves are describes as "[echoes](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/218.htm)" from previous time loops.

> **CRUSHER:** *Can we isolate the voices? Find out what they're saying?*
>
> **DATA:** *Computer, continuous playback please [he pauses] There are approximately one thousand voices overlapping. The voices are those of
>   the Enterprise crew. Our voices.*